# Как узнать кол-во строк из mysql, попадающих под условие where, избегая LIMIT и OFFSET?

Tags: sql

Есть SQL запрос:

```
SELECT  p.link AS link,
        p.id AS id, 
        p.title AS title,
        p.can_use_promocode AS can_use_promocode,                        
        p.price AS price,
        p.sale_price AS sale_price,
        p.sale_percent AS sale_percent,
        p.is_sale AS is_sale,
        p.photo AS photo,
        c1.title AS c1_title,
        c1.link AS c1_link,
        c2.title AS c2_title,
        c2.link AS c2_link
        FROM products AS p
        LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON p.category_parent_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON p.category_children_id = c2.id 
        WHERE p.category_parent_id = :parent_id AND p.category_children_id = :children_id 
        AND ((p.is_sale = 0 AND p.price >= 4000) OR (p.is_sale = 1 AND p.sale_price >= 4000))  
        ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Он выдает данные для определенной страницы пагинации, однако для построения пагинации мне нужно знать и общее кол-во строк (т.е. игнорируя LIMIT и OFFSET). Вопрос: каким образом это сделать?

Comment: тебе нужно что ли SELECT count(id.someontable)+cont(id.comeonetable2)FROM someontable,someontable2;?

Comment: Составляете запрос без лимитов и сдвигов, но не выполняете. Оборачиваете его в конструкцию `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (ваш запрос);`. Добавляете в ваш первый запрос нужные лимиты и сдвиг.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить общее количество записей в том же запросе за один проход таблиц. Это конечно будет медленнее, чем первоначальный запрос, но *может быть* быстрее, чем выполнение отдельного запроса для подсчета количества. И думаю стоило бы сохранить полученное количество и для последующих страниц не вычислять его заново по БД, так как это все таки отнимает существенное время.

```
SELECT  p.link AS link, p.id AS id, p.title AS title,
        p.can_use_promocode AS can_use_promocode, p.price AS price,
        p.sale_price AS sale_price, p.sale_percent AS sale_percent,
        p.is_sale AS is_sale, p.photo AS photo, c1.title AS c1_title,
        c1.link AS c1_link, c2.title AS c2_title, c2.link AS c2_link,
        @cnt as total_count
   FROM (select p.*, @cnt:=@cnt+1
           from products AS p,(select @cnt:=0) X
          WHERE p.category_parent_id = :parent_id AND p.category_children_id =:children_id 
            AND (  (p.is_sale = 0 AND p.price >= 4000)
                OR (p.is_sale = 1 AND p.sale_price >= 4000))
        ) p
   LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON p.category_parent_id = c1.id
   LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON p.category_children_id = c2.id 
  ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, не додумался сначала. Сохранить полученное количество не получится, поскольку при каждом применении фильтра, данный запрос меняет свои условия. Кстати, а что будет быстрее: добавлять условия фильтра в SQL запрос (where) или же выбирать все товары из категории, а потом уже в php через foreach их фильтровать?

Comment: @Alexxosipov Лучше не уровне БД, она лучше заточена на фильтрацию, плюс не надо будет гонять лишние данные БД-приложение и что самое главное, у вас тут join, БД то сначала все фильтры применит, а потом, только к нужным строкам будет получать имена категорий. А если фильтровать в php, то сначала БД ко всем строкам будет категории подбирать, а потом вы часть из них выбросите

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Alexxosipov и на счет "не получиться" это вопрос открытый, вы же наверняка когда будете формировать ссылки на следующие страницы в них будете включать всю информацию по фильтру (ну что бы при выборке второй страницы взять ее по тем же фильтрам), так вот в этих параметрах в ссылке можно и полученное кол-во записей передать...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на этот вопрос с физической точки зрения: чтобы выяснить, сколько строк отвечает вашему запросу, СУБД таки придётся выполнить полный запрос без ограничений. Очевидный способ — вызвать `COUNT` на вашем запросе:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT /* ваш запрос */
    LIMIT /* абсолютное ограничение на пагинацию */
) q
```

Хотите ли вы выполнять полный запрос, если пользователь в большинстве случаев будет смотреть только первую страницу — вопрос открытый: зависит от размера БД, от нагрузки и т. п. Закэширует ли СУБД при подобном запросе весь результат, будет ли его использовать для последующей пагинации — зависит от СУБД.

Comment: Пока что не до конца понял, если честно. СУБД mysql 5.6, пользователи, будут не только первую страницу смотреть, проверено метриками (30% пользователей идут на 2)

Comment: @Alexxosipov Что непонятно? Два запроса выполните: один с подсчётом строк без ограничений / с менее суровым ограничением для отображения кнопок пагинации, другой с ограничениями для выдачи собственно данных.

Comment: вообще задача какая?

Answer (score 1):

Если это MySQL, то: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

> ***SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS*** tells MySQL to calculate how many rows there would be in the result set, disregarding any LIMIT clause. The number of rows can then be retrieved with *SELECT FOUND_ROWS()*

Так  что просто

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.link AS link,
    p.id AS id, 
-- и далее по тексту
-- а потом
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете добавить в свой запрос такой столбец:

```
(select count(*)
FROM products AS p
        LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON p.category_parent_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON p.category_children_id = c2.id 
        WHERE p.category_parent_id = :parent_id AND p.category_children_id = :children_id 
        AND ((p.is_sale = 0 AND p.price >= 4000) OR (p.is_sale = 1 AND p.sale_price >= 4000))
)  qty
```